# EP drop down field doesn't store default value.

Tags: c#, asp.net, axapta, enterprise-portal

In EP page when I click a record on edit mode where it takes to edit page.

A drop down bound field of the record  has default value "none" where when I select a value e.g "accepted" and click on the page back button. The "accepted" value is saved. As I have clicked on the back button, ideally it shouldn't save rather store the "none" value only.

The drop down field has autopostback=true as I wish to enable/disable certain fields based on selection. So can't make the property false.

Please help.